# How to include microphone adjustment in sound menu

Tags: unity, sound, microphone

When I use skype I have 2 scrollbars for the sound:

[image]

How can I keep those 2 scrollbars all the time, and not only when I have skype conversations? When I don't talk with skype, only speaker scrollbar is visible.

Edit1:

Here's an output of `sudo updatedb; locate -r indicator-sound-service$`:

```
/home/dusan/.local/share/Trash/files/build/src/indicator-sound-service
/home/dusan/.local/share/Trash/files/indicator-sound-12.10.2+14.04.20140401/build/src/indicator-sound-service
/home/dusan/.local/share/Trash/files/indicator-sound-12.2.10.2+14.04.20140401/build/src/indicator-sound-service
/home/dusan/.local/share/Trash/files/src/indicator-sound-service
/home/dusan/.local/share/Trash/files/src.2/indicator-sound-service
/home/dusan/.local/share/Trash/files/src.3/indicator-sound-service
/home/dusan/.local/share/Trash/files/src.4/indicator-sound-service
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 14.04

1. Download build dependencies and source

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-sound
   apt-get source indicator-sound
   ```
2. Change `src/volume-control.vala`

   Modify default from `false` to `true`:

   ```
   /** true when a microphone is active **/
   public bool active_mic { get; private set; default = true; }
   ```

   Comment line that sets hiding variable using `//`:

   ```
               case Context.SubscriptionEventType.REMOVE:
                   //this.active_mic = false;
                   break;
   ```
3. Build and install

   ```
   cd indicator-sound-12.10.2+14.04.20140313/
   mkdir build
   cd build/
   cmake ..
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
4. Kill running `indicator-sound-service` or Logout/login

   ```
   pkill -f indicator-sound-service
   ```

[image: show mic always in sound indicator popup]

**Note:**

For some reasons, you may want to skip `sudo make install` or didn't work, then just replace the executable:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
sudo cp src/indicator-sound-service /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
pkill -f indicator-sound-service
```

Comment: It doesn't work for 16.04

Comment: @DusanMilosevic, I will check it after returning from a work trip in few days.

Comment: @DusanMilosevic, in fresh Ubuntu 16.04   I see microphone slider by defaut without any modification.  Could you confirm?

Comment: Yes. I realized it only works for external mics. When I use only my internal laptop microphone, it doesn't. Thank you!