# Cannot download build-dep for indicator-sound

Tags: apt, sound, 16.04

I'm trying to do [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476324/how-to-include-microphone-adjustment-in-sound-menu), but when I execute `sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-sound`, i get `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`. I did not get this error in pervious ubuntu versions, only in 16.04. What sources do I need to add in order to download indicator-sound sources? Thanks!

Edit1:

I can now execute `sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-sound`, but all I get is :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
```

It appeares that I haven't downloaded anything. :(

Edit2: This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list). As you can read in edit1, I cannot download the actual folder with source files.

Edit3: I just realized, I also get these errors when I run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
```

Edit4: I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-automatically-fix-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times), and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce what you saw. Here is what I see: http://paste.ubuntu.com/21010469/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To edit your `sources.list` first you might want to make a backup copy

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
```

then:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

all the `deb-src...` lines are commented out by default. You actually only need to uncomment the first one. Change this:

```
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

to this:

```
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

save and exit and you will be able to run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt build-dep indicator-sound
```

and in your home (it's a good idea to make a directory to unpack sources because they unpack to multiple files so this keeps them together)

```
mkdir indicator-sound; cd indicator-sound
apt source indicator-sound
```

Comment: @DusanMilosevic :) :) pleasure

Comment: Actually, it still, doesn't work. I have updated the question...

Comment: @DusanMilosevic hmmm it worked for me in 16.04 ~20MB of stuff. Did you `sudo apt update` first?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to download source code from the Ubuntu repositories. The GUI way of doing this is:

1. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> to start the Dash and search for "Software & Updates".
2. Check the "Source code" box as shown below:

   [image]
3. Press "Close" and agree to reload `sources.list`.

Comment: Actually, it still, doesn't work. I have updated the question...